# Ошибка при запуске программы. Массив

Tags: c++

Пишет, что `pfunc` не инициализирована в строке `output(arrayX(a, x, pfunc), a);`
Код программы:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define n 5
using namespace std;

void input_kl(int a[n][n])
{
    printf("Введите элементы матрицы A:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
}

void input_f(int a[n][n])
{
    int i, j, k;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\inp.txt", "r");
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n && !feof(fp); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n && !feof(fp); j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i][j]);
            k++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    if (k < n * n)
    {
        printf("Матрица неполная, введите элементы \n");
        for (i = k; i < n; i++)
            for (j = j; j < n; j++)
                scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
    }
}

//
// пример обработки матрицы
//
int* arrayX(int(*a)[n], int* x, void (*pfunc)(int[n][n]))
{
    pfunc(a);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        x[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (a[i][j] < 0)             //  Исправление только здесь
            {                           //  Исправление только здесь
                x[i] = a[i][j];   //  Исправление только здесь
                break;                //  Исправление только здесь 
            }                           //  Исправление только здесь
        }
    }
    return x;
}

void recY(int* array, int arraySize, int& y, int position = 0)
{
    if (position == arraySize) {
        y = -1;
        return;
    }
    if (*(array + position) < 0) {
        y = *(array + position);
        return;
    }
    recY(array, arraySize, y, ++position);
}
void output(int x[], int a[][n])
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\inp.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "Матрица A:\n");
    printf("Mатрица A:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
            fprintf(fp, "%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fprintf(fp, "Massiv X:\n");
    printf("Massiv X:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d ", x[i]);
        printf("%d ", x[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int main()
{
   setlocale( LC_ALL, "Rus" ); 
   int a[n][n], x[n], c;
   void (*pfunc)(int[n][n]);
       do
       {
           printf("Vvod matrici A:\n1-s klaviaturi\n2-iz faila\n");
                scanf("%d",&c);
       }

   while (c != 1 && c != 2);
   // Присваивание указателю адреса одной их функций:
   switch (c)
   {
   case 1: input_kl(a);
       break;
   case 2: input_f(a);
       break;
   }
   output(arrayX(a, x, pfunc), a);
   int y;
   recY(x, 5, y);
   std::cout << "Y : " << y << '\n';
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: а вы что ожидали на выходе, если `pfunc` и правда не инициализирована?

Comment: как это исправить?

Comment: `pfunc` - это указатель на функцию, который работает так же, как и указатель на любой другой объект, т.е. ему нужно присвоить адрес функции с такой же сигнатурой. В вашем коде таких функций две.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по комментарию `// Присваивание указателю адреса одной их функций:`
Код должен выглядеть так:

```
switch (c)
{
    case 1:
        pfunc = input_kl;
        break;
    case 2:
        pfunc = input_f;
        break;
}
```

Comment: исправила, но всё равно error C4703: используется потенциально неинициализированная локальная переменная-указатель "pfunc"

Comment: А каким будет pfunc если ввести не 1 или 2? Ответ - неизвестно чем. Это можно решить, добавив ветку default в switch.